# Why i can not call returned method directly

Tags: erlang, return-type, higher-order-functions

I have the following curious case in Erlang:

```
Tx=fun(A)->G=fun()->A+33 end,G end.
```

I do not understand why i can't call the returned method directly , and need to store it in a variable first:

```
Tx(3)().   ->  1: syntax error before: '(' //why does this not work ?

Var=Tx(3)     //and this
Var()         // works
```

I can not call a method that is returned ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the returned `fun` into brackets:

```erlang
(Tx(3))().
```

Answer (score 3):

It's an order of operations problem. The compiler/runtime doesn't understand what's being returned from `Tx(3)` is a function. By adding `()` around it `(Tx(3))`, `Tx(3)` is evaluated first, is seen as a function, and can then be evaluated again.

Answer (score 0):

this is a high order function(like closure)

```
Tx= fun(A)->
      G=fun()->A+33 end,
     G 
    end.
```

`Tx` is a function where arity = 1, and return a function called `G`

and

`G` with arity = 0